# Is it reliable to call Firebase getToken() from MainActivity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I think that instead of saving the token I get from onTokenRefresh() to another place, why not let Firebase keep it and then I query it directly by using this whenever needed:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

This way, I should be able to get the token from the most reliable source.

But I tried to search it and did not find anything which suggests this use outside the service. I tried to implement it and found that it indeed returns the correct token if onTokenRefresh() is already called, otherwise it returns null. I think this will be the same wherever I manually save the token.

So is there any instruction which discourages the use in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` from anywhere and it will give you the *current* token.

The problem is that there are a few situations you won't catch if you *only* call it in your `MainActivity`:

- the token may not have been created yet, in which return `getToken()` returns `null`.
- the token may get recycled after you call `getToken()`, in which case your code is working with an outdated token.

To ensure you catch both these situations, you should implement `FirebaseInstanceId.onTokenRefresh()`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have seen the token refresh a couple of times, but I have noticed that getToken() always returns the latest token. I also manage it on onTokenRefresh() for other purposes.